# Approximation of Integrable function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be an integrable function over $E$. Then given $ε > 0$, there is a simple function $φ$, step function $ψ$, and a continuous function $g$ supported on a finite measure set such that   
$\int_E|f − φ| < ε$, $\int_E|f − ψ| < ε$, $\int_E|f − g| < ε$.

Now I know one result that if Let $f$ be a measurable function over $E$. Then given $ε > 0$, there is a simple function $φ$, step function $ψ$, and a continuous function $g$ supported on a finite measure set such that $|f − φ| < ε$, $|f − ψ| < ε$, $|f − g| < ε$ a.e .

Now for $f$ integrable $\int_E f=\int_E f^+ - \int_E f^- <\infty$ where $f^+$ and $f^-$ are non-negative functions so from the definition of non-negative function integrable $\int_E f=sup_{0\leq h\leq f} \int_Eh$ where $h:E \to \Bbb R$ bounded, supported on a finite measurable set.

So my question is

- Is $h$ measurable here?( Because I have an intution that $h$ is measurable here)
- If it is then how to prove the main question?

Comment: What does $E$ denote?

Comment: A subset of $\Bbb R$. I don't know any more information about $E$.. Rest we have derive from the hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

Let's prove a stronger result: For any $f\in L^1(R)$, then given ε>0, there is a simple function φ, step function ψ, and a continuous function g with compact support such that $\int_E|f − φ| < ε,\int_E|f − ψ| < ε,\int_E|f − g| < ε$.

If this proposition is proved, then your question is proved,too. As we can let f vanish outside E , then f becomes a function $\in L^1(R)$.

Step1: For simple functions

There is a increasing sequence of simple functions that converge a.e. to f, i.e.,
$0{\le\varphi}_1\le\varphi_2\le\cdots\le f$

$\varphi_n\rightarrow f,a.e.,as\ n\rightarrow+\infty$

As $\left|\varphi_n-f\right|\le2\left|f\right|$, which is integrable on R. LDC now gives that $\  {\int_{E}{\left|\varphi_n-f\right|\rightarrow0},{n\rightarrow+\infty}}$

Step2: For continuous function with compact support.

For each $\varphi_n$, Lusin Theorem gives a continuous function with compact support g, s.t.sup g